# Is there such a thing as the C#'s `#region` keyword in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In C# I can use the `#region` keyword to separate blocks of code. Does something like it exist in Ruby?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what it does (otherwise, only devs who do both C# and Ruby can help you). Googling it makes it look like a comment that hints to Visual Studo how to do code folding. Since Ruby has no official editor, there is no such such magic comment. If you commonly use some editor and it is extensible, then there is nothing preventing you from making such a magic comment. Most editors have their syntax files open source, it would probably not be much work to edit the syntax file to recognize such a construct.

Comment: Ruby does not have preprocessor directives like C#

Comment: The convenient thing is you can use `#pragma` or `#region` if you like as they're both valid comments that an editor can be customized to recognize.

Comment: If you are using VS Code as Editor you can use the extension "#region folding for VS Code". There you can configure the folding comment for each language as you wish.
For an example see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62137222/2408013

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: There is no code folding or comment style convention enforced by the ruby language. You can use your own convention for grouping methods however and setup your text editor to fold code in a way that works well for you (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding).

Answer (score 4):

Many wont like this answer, but its simple, and it works

```
if region1=true

    #your code/comments here

end #region1
```

this is of course, if `region1` is not a variable you need at that scope

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion: put code you'd have in a C# `#region` into a ruby `module`.

A [#region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) comment in C# is used for code folding in Visual Studio. You can group similar code into a region like:

```
#region Some Info here to see when folded
 methodA() {}
 methodB() {}
#endregion
```

If you find yourself asking "is there a ruby equivalent to C Sharp region", it's time to have a look at [modules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html) in the ruby language. With modules you can group code AND share code between classes (instead of using inheritance, interface or else).

Example:

```
class A
  module AMod # you can put the module into a file, too
    def a_method
      # do stuff
    end
    # some methods
  end

  include AMod
end
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer: Use Emacs. It doesn't seem to answer your question, but it does.