# How to do Region Blocks for Code Folding in android studio with Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I can do region blocks in android studio like this.

```
//region Description

Your code here

//endregion
```

But how to the same with flutter ?

Answer (score 5):

In the IntelliJ or Android Studio IDE, you can use REGION folding as written in your question, works fine.
REGION folding also works with `//#region` (both tested in the IntelliJ IDE CE 2019.3.3 and Android Studio IDE 3.4.1):

```dart
// with and without spaces after double slashes
//#region Description
Your code here
//#endregion

// #region Description
Your code here
// #endregion
```

This was also described in the Dart-Code/Dart-Code repository in [this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1232#issuecomment-510917252)

Off topic:
If someone else prefers to use VSCode then I can recommend the extension [#region folding for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder). There you can configure the folding comment for each language as you wish.

```
"maptz.regionfolder": {
     "[dart]": {
         "foldStart": "// #region [NAME]", // or whatever you like, e.g.`// #some_tag#`
         ...
     }
}
```